# Recursion stackOverflowError when finding empty cells in Minesweeper game

Tags: java, recursion, stack-overflow, minesweeper

EDIT: SOLVED!
I simply forgot to include an 'else' statement under the 'else if' which does a blank return

I'm using Java, and I'm making a Minesweeper game.

I am trying to open all adjacent empty cells when an empty cell is clicked.
I have taken a look at similar question on this site and can't see where I'm going wrong.
I am getting a stackOverflow.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Below, the 'buttons' array is a 2D array of buttons, and the 'cells' array is a 2D array of cell objects (used to determine the state of that cell). Obviously each cell corresponds to a button.

```
public void findEmptyCells(int i, int j) // this method is called when a cell is clicked, therefore all adjacent empty cells will be opened
{
    if (i >= 0 && j >= 0 && i < 9 && j < 9) //ie the block actually exists on the grid
    {
        if (cells[i][j].getAdjMines() == 0 && cells[i][j].getIsMine() == false && cells[i][j].getIsFlagged() == false && cells[i][j].getIsOpen() == false) //if cell is empty & not a mine & not flagged
        {
            buttons[i][j].setIcon(new ImageIcon("buttonImages/but" + cells[i][j].getAdjMines() + ".png")); //here the getAdjMines value will be 0, so the empty cell icon will be placed
            cells[i][j].setIsOpen(true); //for later, if we need to identify which cells are still unclicked

            //now to check all adjacent cells
            findEmptyCells(i - 1, j); //left 
            findEmptyCells(i + 1, j); //right 
            findEmptyCells(i, j + 1); //up
            findEmptyCells(i, j - 1); //down
            findEmptyCells(i - 1, j + 1); //up-left
            findEmptyCells(i + 1, j + 1); //up-right
            findEmptyCells(i - 1, j - 1); //down-left
            findEmptyCells(i + 1, j - 1); //down-right

        }
        else if (cells[i][j].getAdjMines() > 0)
        {
            buttons[i][j].setIcon(new ImageIcon("buttonImages/but" + cells[i][j].getAdjMines() + ".png"));
            cells[i][j].setIsOpen(true); //for later, if we need to identify which cells are still unclicked
            return;
        }

    }
    else
    {
      return;  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your `getIsOpen` and `setIsOpen` methods are working as intended. Those are the ones that are key to stopping recursion, so my guess is that there's something wrong there.